# XML writing through jsp

Tags: xml, jsp, scriptlet

```
<%
namespace WritingXml {       
    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("NFrame.xml");              
    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();             
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("device");              
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("device");             
    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("timestamp", "time");             
    xmlWriter.WriteString("id");               
    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();             
    xmlWriter.Close();         
};
%>
```

I am using this code in JSP page for XML writing but I am getting error to insert `;` to complete the declaration of local variable

Comment: are you using any API to to generate XML ?

Comment: are you sure that this the JAVA code ?

Comment: i am using this code in jsp page. whem i am removing this block and simply writing this code within <% %> then m getting error for XmlWriter class

Comment: please post code for import statement include in JSP file for this code.